# Как работать с общими данными в нескольких WCF сервисах?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Допустим у нас есть 2 `WCF` сервиса, которые хостятся на сервере:

1. Пользователь при входе в программу отправляет инфу на сервер что он зашел. Сервер хранит коллбэки всех пользователей которые сейчас в сети.
2. Второй сервис дуплексный и он хочет просто отправить какие-то данные определенному пользователю, но для этого эму нужно получить коллбэк из первого сервиса.

Как правильно в данной ситуации нужно действовать?

Comment: хм... а вы странного хотите, колбеки прописываются в контракте сервиса и просто так их передать с одного сервиса на другой не получится, они к контексту соединения привязаны. Клиент в любом случае должен иметь привязку к обоим сервисам, если должен работать с обоими, а значит во втором уже будут доступны колбеки клиента. Или я не правильно вас понял?

Comment: @rdorn, Да, я понял свою ошибку. Получается что каждая дуплексная служба должна хранить список коллбэков?

Comment: точнее не хранить, колбеки предоставляются контекстом соединения. Пропал контекст - пропали и колбеки. самому их хранить не нужно

Comment: оформил почеловечески

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У дуплексных служб, колбеки от клиента прописываются в контракте. Когда клиент подключается, он передает свой контекст сервису и сервис получает через этот контекст доступ к колбекам клиента. Передача контекста между сервисами не предусмотрена, т.к. в зависимости от настроек сервиса создается отдельный инстанс сервиса на подключение или сессию для каждого клиента.

Если ваше приложение использует больше одного сервиса в своей работе, то оно обязано подключаться к каждому из них независимо, таким образом необходимости в передаче контекста между службами просто не может быть.